# Избежать проблемы с кешем при использовании import | JS

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Я изучаю JS и пришел к выводу, что гораздо лучше и правильнее использовать модульность при помощи import, чем хардкорить, прописывая `<script>` в index.php на каждый js скрипт. Однако возникла проблема с кешем. Если раньше, прописывая `<script>` я добавлял в конец адреса скрипта GET запрос с временем последнего изменения файла (чтобы пользователь читал скрипт из кеша, а если он изменился, то закачивал с сервера один раз и потом снова читал из кеша). Это работало, однако это не работает с import. Если я даже и изменяю JS модуль, подключенный через import, то браузер все равно читает файл из кеша и не видит изменения.

Как этого избежать? Снова переходить на `<script>`?

P.S. Я уже гуглил мой вопрос и нашел псевдохардкорные варианты решения:

1. Подключать php, который подключает js.
2. Размещать js по пути типа: `/modules/1.1.2/script.js` и менять версию в пути

Данные решения меня не устраивают. Первый в силу своей костыльности, а второй в силу ручного рукоблудства при изменении содержимого скрипта (доступа к .htaccess у меня нет).

Comment: Можете использовать webpack, он сам всё переименует.

Comment: @nazarpunk мне кажется, что это неплохой совет. Однако есть ли способы делать это на чистом JS без сторонних подключений и, желательно, jQuery?

Comment: если на сервере настроен [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) то вообще ничего делать не нужно, всё само прекрасно работает. Если вы конечно не кешируете через ServiceWorker, там свои ньюансы есть. Использование jQuery в 2021 выглядит сомнительно. А на чистом js вы это не решите. Если не хотите использовать webpack, то можете посмотреть в сторону gulp.

Comment: @nazarpunk проблема в том, что у меня доступ только к части файловой системы сайта и все. Даже доступа к основному .htaccess нет. Не говоря уже о настройках сервера, так что webpack я не могу поставить, увы. Однако это хороший вариант и я возьму его на заметку, если в будущем столкнусь с этой проблемой

Comment: Так webpack и gulp нужен только для разработчиков и на сервер не ставится. Основная идея сформировать файлы и залить их на сервер.

Comment: @nazarpunk да, я сейчас почитал документацию и познакомился с webpack получше. Думаю он мне подойдет. Большое спасибо, выручили)